# Movie/CGI in which a genetically engineered organism can turn electronic items into living things and also control them

Tags: story-identification, movie, cgi

I cannot properly recall, but it was about some genetically engineered organism that can turn any electronic item into a living thing and also control them.

Then the president's son goes missing with a laptop, that I think contained something important. He wakes up to be found in some sort of tribe, and yeah the weapon to destroy this organism is generated by some Cool Industries (actual name) weapon called Cool Bomb (actual name).

It also has a scene in which a satellite, controlled by the organism, crashes in the tribe's forest, and an elder (80 or 90 I think) woman tries to talk to machine, thinking of it as the wrath of God and asking its reason. The boy makes fun of them, only to be scolded by a woman.

Then the satellite transforms into something else (yeah, I forgot to mention that the organism can also transform items into other things) and attacks all of them, but the tribe destroys all the attackers (remember it was animated/CGI). Don't know if it was a movie or just a CGI video.

Comment: Roughly when did you watch this?

Comment: Well roughly it was like 2018 or 2019  I think I saw it on tv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Thai 3D-animated film [Echo Planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_Planet) (AKA Adventure Planet) from 2012.

> **Sam is the spoiled and disgruntled son of the Capital City president.** During a trip with the scouts, the child, who relies too much on technology, **gets lost and ends up in the rural village of an exotic country** where Nora and her brother Kim live. When an ecological disaster of biblical proportions threatens to destroy the Earth, the trio join forces in an attempt to save the planet, endangered not only by global warming but also by scientists and world politicians who think they are fighting the threat with **cold bombs.**

They're battling an organism that consumes energy. The film is currently available (in Thai) on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRIFsgKx0tE), and you can see the satellite crashing into the tribe's forest in the trailer around 0:56:

Comment: This is yhe the movie thankyou