# Movie about a boy scout member who saves the future earth with a tribal girl from the nuclear made villans

Tags: story-identification, movie, cartoon

A boy of boys scout was the son of the president of that country dont remember clearly but he was flying a jet plane and crash landed in a forest then he met that tribal girl and her little brother. They save him. That boy's father launched a nuclear ray on the ozone layer for it to repair by it but the ozone layer got destroyed and some creature come on earth and destroyed everything.That boy and the girl saved the future earth from a tree by communicating all the plants and tree through a tree to save the earth then they also rush to the place the meeting was held to launch the nuclear ray and turn off all power supply in the world for the creatures to become weak. That's the story of anyone knows please let me know. Thank you

Comment: Can you give us more information about this.  How long ago did you read/watch it? Was it in English?

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons as per the [tour].

Comment: You can still [edit] your question to clarify it.

Answer (score 2):

*Adventure Planet*, aka *Echo Planet*, originally released in Thailand as *Echo Jew Gong Lok*. From the review on [this site](http://www.synopsisandtrailers.com/year-round/company.php?market=year-round&ID=1391) under the name of *Echo Planet*:

[image: DVD cover for Adventure Planet]

> Jorpe is a gifted child able to communicate with nature; his elder sister Norva is an expert of local herbs and her tribe's martial arts. Together they encounter Sam, son of the President of Capital State, when he becomes lost in their jungle. Excessive global warming has attracted B.U.C.T. heat devils that are reproducing at an alarming rate, devouring the world's energy. World leaders come together and unanimously decide to use a new weapon called the "Cool Bomb". Only Jorpe, Norva and Sam know that there is a better solution to save the planet. The flawed "Cool Bomb" will in fact destroy the ozone layer, upsetting the balance of nature and potentially ending all human life...

Found with a search for `animated film "son of the president" "ozone layer"`

### Trailer

Comment: Thank you so much i was looking up for this movie for but nothing came up as result thank you

Comment: Don't forget to accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: Huh, and it will be a dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/241966/movie-cgi-in-which-a-genetically-engineered-organism-can-turn-electronic-items-i/244331#244331